# Information given in dream to some and to others in person

Tags: matthew, luke, angels, joseph, mary

Both the Maggi (Matthew 3:12) and Joseph (Matthew 3:13,19) receive information in a dream, whereas Zechariah and Mary receive information personally (Luke). Why is that?

One could simply state that it's because God wanted it that way. As well that God knows our hearts and we are not all hands.

Yet wondering if there's anything I'm missing here.

Somehow related: [What is the difference in response between Zechariah and Mary?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/716/27054)

Comment: There is no answer to this question - God delivers messages to people according to His divine wisdom and will.  Save this question for when you meet Him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dottard has said, there is no answer to this question.

In order to answer this question we would need something in the Bible to tell us why God spoke to the Maggi and Joseph via dream while Zechariah and Mary were sent an angel.

Or, why Moses was given a burning bush etc.

Since we are not given the explanation in Scripture good hermeneutics leads us to say that we have no authoritative answer.

There are those who will try to use reason to arrive at an answer or simple conjecture. The goal of hermeneutics is to let Scripture speak for itself.